# Linux tool for triggering data updates and transformations (low-end ETL/data warehousing tool)

Tags: triggers, dependencies, etl, data-warehouse

I have a bunch of scripts collecting data from internet and local services, writing them to disk, scripts transforming the data and writing it into a database, scripts reading data from the database and generating new data, etc, written in bash, Python, SQL, ... (Linux).

Apart from a few time-triggered scripts, the glue between the scripts is currently me, running the scripts now and then in a particular order to update everything.

*What is the simplest way to replace me by a tool that observes dependencies and triggers the next step as soon as the preconditions are met?*

I've found many ETL and data warehousing tools, but these seem too heavy weight for my simple setting. I'd prefer a CLI solution with text-based configuration (maybe able to visualise the graph of dependencies). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try airflow: [airflow.apache.org](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/index.html)